# SKLabelNode not showing up on screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

in a private interface

```
   @property BOOL contentCreated
```

And then in the implementation

```
//just like in Apple's example project

- (void)didMoveToView: (SKView *) view {
   if (!self.contentCreated) {
       [self createSceneContents];
       self.contentCreated = YES;
   }
}

- (void)createSceneContents {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    SKLabelNode *newGameNode = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:
        @"Helvetica"];
    newGameNode.name = @"NewGame";
    newGameNode.text = @"New Game";
    newGameNode.fontSize = 30;
    newGameNode.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    newGameNode.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    [self addChild:newGameNode];
}
```

but when I run, nothing shows up on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are displaying white text on a white background. Try this:

```
newGameNode.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
```

Comment: That's called a "whiteout" :)

Comment: I changed it, and although this was a problem, it did not fix it. Still not showing up. Any other ideas?

Comment: other than the colour, the code is fine - set up a breakpoint in the `createSceneContents` method to verify it's indeed being called. or just put its contents inside the init method of the scene to double-check?

Comment: i tried this and I am sure the code is getting called, yet still nothing... any other ideas? thanks for your help

Comment: figured out my problem. I did [myScene alloc] init] not initWithSize:] like i needed to. thanks guys

Comment: @Lucas This helped me. You should put this info in an answer to this question, rather than burying it in the comments. Two benefits: easier to find, and we can upvote you! Yes, you can answer your own question, people do it all the time.